# Leer fichero con nombre dinámico

Tags: java

Supongamos que tengo  una carpeta con estos ficheros, el nombre esta compuesto por Test + fechas + hora:

```
Test_01032021_1100.xlsx
Test_01032021_1300.xlsx
Test_01032021_1600.xlsx
Test_01032021_1900.xlsx
```

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy");
String filename = "Test_" + df.format(new Date()) + ".xlsx";
XSSFWorkbookworkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(fileName));
```

Suponiendo que son las 17:00 deberia leer el fichero Test_01032021_1600.xlsx ya que es la hora más cercana.¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Para leer el fichero, necesitas saber el nombre del mismo. `Date()` al parecer no devuelve lo que esperas: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date--

Comment: por eso formateo la fecha a ddMMyyyy, con eso ya tengo parte  del nombre solo me faltaria saber que hora deberia leer.

Comment: Vale, ahora entiendo lo que comentas. Yo lo que haría es listar el contenido de la carpeta y coger los ficheros que comiencen por la fecha que necesitas. Ya de ahí puedes obtener el más reciente a la hora que necesites.